# toggleClass working only when .className is used

Tags: jquery

I have a button to toggle sidemenu. for that i used jquery toggleClass on buton click.It is only working when toggleClass(".right-nav--small") is used.Can anyone help me with this issue since i am new tojquery.Thanks for the help in advance

```js
$(".right-nav__show_i").click(function() {
  // alert("side menu width toggle");

  $(".right-nav").toggleClass(".right-nav--small");
});
```

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail, pls

Comment: That is not how `toggleClass` works, so in order to help you we need to see your html code and other relevant code like css, and html